# How to configure the router between two different internal network in Virtualbox?

Tags: router, virtual-machine, firewall, openbsd, pf

I would like to build this network in Virtualbox:

[image]

I use OpenBSD for routers, this OS is pretty easy,and well commented to configure, however I still got one problem. Router named router02 can access internet through router01, and devices in LAN network can talk with router02. So, something happening in router02,therefore LAN network cannot access net through router01. I would like to access network from LAN internal network too,and later to have a both way communication between this two subnet. I guess the problem is with the pf.conf file,but I cannot find it.

### router01 has two NICs:

- `em0` -> NAT;
- `em1` -> Internal CARD (named DMZ);

#### /etc/hostname.em1

```
192.168.10.1 255.255.255.0
```

#### /etc/hostname.em0

```
dhcp
```

#### /etc/pf.conf

```
pass out on em0 inet from 192.168.10.0/24 to any flags S/SA nat to (em0) round-robin
pass out on em0 inet from 192.168.100.0/24 to any flags S/SA nat to (em0) round-robin
```

---

### router02 has two NICs:

- `em0` -> Internal CARD (named DMZ);
- `em1` -> Internal CARD (named LAN);

#### /etc/hostname.em1

```
192.168.100.1 255.255.255.0
```

#### /etc/hostname.em0

```
192.168.10.2 255.255.255.0
```

#### /etc/mygate

```
192.168.10.1
```

#### /etc/pf.conf

```
pass out on em0 inet from 192.168.100.0/24 to 192.168.10.1/24
```

(I do not want yet any complicated pf configuration,just to pass every packets.)

Comment: You should use NAT on router02 too. The way it is now, you send out packets from em0 of router02 with source addresses in the range 192.168.100.0/24. Most probably the windows server and router01 do not know where to route the replies, so there's no communication. If you do not want to NAT on router02, then you have to edit -a lot- the routing tables of router01 and windows server.

Comment: In fact it's not just that they don't know where to send the replies, they probably don't even acknowledge the packets, since they're not addressed to them.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the routing table on router01 (using either `route show` or `netstat -r`) you'll find that traffic for 192.168.10.0/24 will go out through `em1`, and everything else will go through the default route, which is set by `dhclient` on `em0`.  When router01 gets a packet from 192.168.100.0/24 on `em1` it'll reply on `em0` because there is no entry for that subnet on the routing table. So it'll use the default route.  You can easily check this by doing e.g.

```
$ route get 192.168.100.1
```

on router01.  Note the destination and interface name on the reply.

router02 can access the internet through router01 because in that case requests come from the DMZ interface on router2 (192.168.10.2), and that's on the same subnet as `em1` on router01.  So when router01 replies, it replies through `em1` because that's the route for 192.168.10.0/24.

You have two possible solutions: either use NAT on router02 (this means all request from LAN will reach router01 with 192.168.10.2 as a source address) which will work but means extra load on router02, or just do the more logical thing which is to add a route to your LAN on router01, so that it knows that traffic to that subnet must go through router02:

```
# route add 192.168.100.0/24 192.168.10.2
```

You can make this permanent by adding the following line to `/etc/hostname.em1`:

```
!route add 192.168.100.0/24 192.168.10.2
```